# Is there a way to assign existing "feature" to epic?

Tags: scrum, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio online as our backlog/sprint planning system. Now VSO development team has introduced possibility to define **epics**, which is great.

But the problem is that I already have full backlog with features and backlog items. I can not find a way how to assign those features to newly created epics... (the same if I have created backlog item first and after that - if I create a feature, I can't find a way how to attach that aforementioned backlog item to the newly created feature)

I am stuck and can't find a way how to accomplish this. Is it at all possible? Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, follow the steps below to accomplish this:

**From Epics:**

1. Open the Epics item.
2. Click "Link to..." button under "Features" tab.
3. Select "Child" link type and enter the ID of the feature you'd like to assign to this Epic.
   [image]

**From Features**

1. Set "Mapping" to "On" and you will see the Epics listed in the right
   panel.
2. Drag and drop the feature to the Epic you'd like to assign.[image]

Or you can also:

1. Open the feature item.
2. Click "Link to..." button under "All Links" tab.
3. Set "Link Type" to "Parent" and enter the ID of the Epic you'd like to assign.

[image]

The steps above can be also used when you want to assign backlog item to feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Plus I found out, that from Features it is possible to select Parents = show and then it is possible to link feature to epic with drag and drop within the same hierarchical list

Comment: @Prokurors yups you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64990832/736079

Answer (score 4):

An easier way is to use the "Mapping" pane on the "Backlogs" tab:

- Go to the "Feature" level
- Activate the "Mapping" pane

[image]

Now simply drag & drop your features onto the epic you want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Epic work item form should have a FEATURES tab where you can associate existing or add new features (that are automatically associated to the Epic)

[image]